# jQuery & Bootstrap show password not working with dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show/hide passwords on dynamically created forms using jQuery and Bootstrap but I am having a hard time getting the script to "see" the dynamic forms.

I can add new forum inputs with the button and the "eye" is visible but clicking the eye does not toggle the password visibility.

How would I make it so each input element has its own password toggle?

It would be great to have solutions explained as I am still learning JS and would like to learn as much as possible.

Here is what I have so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- HIDDEN DYNAMIC ELEMENT TO CLONE - server info -->
  <div class="form-group dynamic-element-server" style="display:none">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="password1" class="form-control password1" type="password" name="serverpass[]" value="123">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <p class="delete">DELETE</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF HIDDEN ELEMENT -->


  <div class="form-container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>

        <legend class="title">Servers</legend>

        <div class="dynamic-stuff-server">
          <!-- Dynamic element will be cloned here -->
          <!-- You can call clone function once if you want it to show it a first element-->
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="add-one-server add-button"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> server</button></p>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.1.2/bootstrap-show-password.js'></script>
  <script>
    //Clone the hidden element and shows it   
    $('.add-one-server').click(function() {
      $('.dynamic-element-server').first().clone().appendTo('.dynamic-stuff-server').show();
      attach_delete();
    });

    //Attach functionality to delete buttons
    function attach_delete() {
      $('.delete').off();
      $('.delete').click(function() {
        console.log("click");
        $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
      });
    }
    $(".password1").password({
      eyeClass: "fa",
      eyeOpenClass: "fa-eye",
      eyeCloseClass: "fa-eye-slash"
    });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The way it is implemented you have several password fields all with same ID = "password1" which is wrong. Give your password field a class and use that class name to select all password fields.

Comment: @NawedKhan Oops, I forgot to change it to a class but you get the same results when it is a class as well. Its like JS doesnt recognize the live injected elements. It also needs to target the password fields in a unique manner as to not reveal all password inputs at the same time.

Comment: You need to use event delegation to trigger events on dynamically created elements

Comment: As Michael and Ercan said you need to call the password thing everytime a new clone is added. I'd move the whole $('.password1').password() code to a function and call this function once onload and then again inside the add server function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should run `password()` function for every added element. so keep a counter for password ids. also, don't run `password()` on the load.

```js
var counter=1;
$('.add-one-server').click(function () {
counter+=1;
var newElementId='password'+counter;

var newElement= $('.dynamic-element-server').first().clone();
  newElement.find('.password1').attr('id',newElementId);
              newElement.appendTo('.dynamic-stuff-server').show();
              attach_delete();
  
   $("#"+newElementId).password({
                eyeClass: "fa",
                eyeOpenClass: "fa-eye",
                eyeCloseClass: "fa-eye-slash"
            });
            });

            //Attach functionality to delete buttons
            function attach_delete() {
              $('.delete').off();
              $('.delete').click(function () {
                console.log("click");
                $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
              });
            }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- HIDDEN DYNAMIC ELEMENT TO CLONE - server info -->
        <div class="form-group dynamic-element-server" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="password1" class="form-control password1" type="password" name="serverpass[]" value="123">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <p class="delete">DELETE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF HIDDEN ELEMENT -->


        <div class="form-container">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>

                    <legend class="title">Servers</legend>

                    <div class="dynamic-stuff-server">
                        <!-- Dynamic element will be cloned here -->
                        <!-- You can call clone function once if you want it to show it a first element-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="add-one-server add-button"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> server</button></p>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.1.2/bootstrap-show-password.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this example and explanation it is working as desired.